# How to pass variable as a parameter in api call fetch in javascript, react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

i am using this api https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/south-africa to get results for my app. What i need to do is instead of writing the country name, i will use a variable which will contain the country name. I need to pass it in the api url

```
var countryName = "south-africa"
const fetchAPI = ()=> {
    return fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/$countryName")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      //console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using string literal.

```
var countryName = "south-africa"
const fetchAPI = ()=> {
    return fetch(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${countryName}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {

    }
```

Or String Concatenation:

```
var countryName = "south-africa"
const fetchAPI = ()=> {
    return fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/" + countryName)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {

    }
```

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: the concatenation worked . string literal did not work

Comment: enable chat i will share there

Answer (score 3):

You can use a template string to achieve that use backticks ` instead of quotes ".

```
var countryName = "south-africa"
const fetchAPI = ()=> {
    return fetch(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${countryName}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      //console.log(result)
```

How to use template strings in javascript.

```js
var foo = 'Hello world'


// expected result "my variable foo = Hello world"
console.log(`my variable foo = ${foo}`)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

My bet would be to use the Javascript string format with magic quotes:

This would lead to

```
var countryName = "south-africa"
const fetchAPI = ()=> {
    return fetch(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${countryName}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      //console.log(result)
```

#### Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals